# httpie gives me an error on macosx 'HTTPConnection'

Tags: macos, httpie

I'm working on macosx and I try to use httpie (with Symfony2 and FOSRestBundle).
I follow different tutorial on how to install `httpie`.

When I try to launch with: `http httpie.org`

I received the following error :

```
http: error: AttributeError: 'HTTPConnection' object has no attribute '_tunnel_host'
```

I can't find anything on Google.

Do I have to configure something special or do I have to install another thing ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. I'd try to update/reinstall HTTPie (`pip install --force-reinstall --upgrade httpie`), and [fill a bug report](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues/new) if it doesn't help.